# Tag the currently open file (not via Finder)

Tags: automation, finder-tag

Is it possible (either natively or with a 3rd party app) to tag a file that is currently open and focused without depending on that app to support tags?

I want to be able to easily and quickly add tags to a file I am editing with my text editor. This editor doesn't support adding tags itself. I also don't want to have to find the file in Finder and add tags there.

I was wondering was this possible, maybe via something like Alfred?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here..if an App doesn't support tags (which I can't find any of in the Apps I have installed personally), then the fall back would be Finder.  Any workflow that runs through Alfred would still be via Finder.  It would be immensely helpful if you provide details of the problem (which editor doesn't support tags with screenshot) and  how you see this workflow progressing.

Comment: I'm using Typora as an editor, which doesn't support tags. That said, I use this to edit notes as it has good markdown support. I have already created a number of workflows to create and search for these notes and open them with Typora. I would like a way to apply tags to the currently open Typora file without having to manually open a finder Window, select the file I'm editing and apply the tags. I was wondering was there something (like Alfred) that could detect the currently open/focused file and apply the tags automatically via finder.

Comment: So, in effect, you want the document open in an app to end up with a Finder metadata tag and hope to automate this?

Comment: @Allan At least preview offers tagging files in the Save pane.